# avoid page unresponsive when doing operations in background

Tags: jquery, performance, datatables

i am loading more than 10000 records in datatable in settimeout function but the page is unresponsive until that background operation is completed.

need to avoid the page unresponsive eventhough doing background operations. any idea?

setTimeOut fn:

```
 setTimeout(function () {                
                var table = $('#tbcont').dataTable(); var str = '';
                for (var i = 300; i < rem_Data.length; i++) {
                    vehicle.push(rem_Data[i].Vehicleno);
                    str += "<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + " </td><td><span class='cls_ind_img' id='vehstatus" + i + "'><img src='/Images/CarPosition/" + rem_Data[i].Status + "'/></span></td>" +
                        "<td><span style='cursor: pointer;' onclick=senddata('" + "VehiclebasedDashboard.aspx?vehicleNo=" + rem_Data[i].Vehicleno + "') id='vehno" + i + "'>" + rem_Data[i].Vehicleno + "</span></td><td><span id='tracktime" + i + "'>" + rem_Data[i].TrackTime + "</span></td>" +
                        "<td><span id='location" + i + "'>" + rem_Data[i].location + "</span></td><td><span  id='speed" + i + "'>" + rem_Data[i].Speed + "</span></td><td><span class='cls_ind_img' id='ignition" + i + "'><img width='20' height='20' src='/Images/" + $.trim(rem_Data[i].Ignition) + ".png'/></span></td></tr>";
                }
                if (rem_Data.length > 300) {
                    $('#tbcont').dataTable().fnDestroy();
                    $('#tbcont tbody').append(str);
                    configtable('#tbcont');
                   $('#tbcont thead tr td div').each(function (index, element) {
                        $('#tbcont tbody tr td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').css('width', $(element).width() + 1 + 'px')
                    });
                    $('#tbcont tr td').css('padding', '3px 2px');
                    $('.cls_ind_img').parent().addClass('cls_ind_img');
                    $("#tbcont_wrapper").css("width", $('#tbcont thead tr').width() + 4 + 'px');
                    $('#tbcont tbody tr').css('display', 'block');                
                }                                                 
            }, 100)
```

Comment: you would probably use some paging instead, to avoi loading so many records at once

Comment: paging is already used, is there any way to do background operation without page unresponsive

Comment: How do you load the records? Let us see the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking **asynchronous** requests: AJAX request

- load your page as usual without performing the database query but displaying e.g. a loading.gif
- invoke an AJAX request with Javascript to a script that's performing the database query only
- handle the return of the request in the AJAX callback, e.g. append the html to a div or evaluate the returned JSON

Also, you can separate your data queries into several chunks (e.g. entries 1-5000, 5001-10000, etc.)

Comment: i am loading records by spliting only,need help to avoid page unresponsive

Comment: Good, because there I'm pointing to the search term "asynchronous requests" for "avoid page unresponsive". Have you investigated what an AJAX request is, yet?

Comment: yah, by default ajax call in jquery is asynchronous request.